# XAML:Maui FontAttributes not working with DataTrigger

Tags: xaml, maui

For this example I have 2 columns

1st column:

working :

```xml
<Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Description}"/>
```

not working:

```xml
<Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource LabelChangedStyle}" />
```

2nd column: working

But I have to make that data triggers work cause the `FontAttribute` shouldn't always have to be ***bold***.

Can someone help pls? thanks

[image: screenshot]

```xml
<Grid BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".4*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".8*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!--<Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Title}"/>-->
    <Label Grid.Column="0" >
        <Label.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                         Binding="{Binding IsRead}"
                         Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Description}"/>
                <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource LabelChangedStyle}" />
            </DataTrigger>
    
            <DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                         Binding="{Binding IsRead}"
                         Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Description}"/>
                <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Label.Triggers>
    </Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" >
        <Label.FormattedText>
            <FormattedString>
                <Span Text="{Binding Description}"  Style="{StaticResource LabelChangedStyle}"/>
            </FormattedString>
        </Label.FormattedText>
    </Label>
</Grid>
```

```xml
<Style x:Key="LabelChangedStyle" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold,Italic" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updates**: if you want to use binding for FontAttributes, you could try:

```
<Label 
   Text="Description"
   FontAttributes="{Binding MyFontAttributes}"
   VerticalOptions="Center" 
   HorizontalOptions="Center"
   Padding="20" />
```

In viewmodel:

```
public FontAttributes MyFontAttributes { get; set; }

public MyPageViewModel() 
{
...
    MyFontAttributes= FontAttributes.Italic | FontAttributes.Bold;
}
```

---

I suggest defining two styles separately according to different values of `IsRead`.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="LabelChangedStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold,Italic" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="LabelDefautStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
    </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

And consume the style separately:

```
<DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                             Binding="{Binding IsRead}"
                             Value="false">
    ...
    <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource LabelChangedStyle}" />
</DataTrigger>

<DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                             Binding="{Binding IsRead}"
                             Value="true">
    ...
    <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource LabelDefautStyle}" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! this one works but is there a way where I can use Binding in FontAttributes of label in a list?

Comment: Thanks for your response! Do you mean use Binding for the FontAttributes  of label in a listview? You can use binding for FontAttributes as it's a BindableProperty. And it would be better if you could share some relevant code to describe what you want to achieve. See my updates.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Liqun

This is how I do the bindings and its also working fine. Not sure though if its a good practice.

```
<Label  Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Title}" FontAttributes="{Binding BoldOrNot}" />

<Label  Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}" FontAttributes="{Binding BoldAndItalic}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"   />
```

Model:

```
public FontAttributes BoldAndItalic
    {
        get
        {
            if (!IsRead)
                return FontAttributes.Bold | FontAttributes.Italic;
            else
                return FontAttributes.Italic;
        }
    }
    public FontAttributes BoldOrNot
    {
        get
        {
            if (!IsRead)
                return FontAttributes.Bold;
            else
                return FontAttributes.None;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes it works, And when ```IsRead```  property is changed, you should also raise property changed for FontAttribute property.

Comment: Glad it works! You could mark the answer which may help others with similar questions.